# Failed docker-push for GCR in wercker

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, wercker

I am using wercker.
I am trying to push the container for GCR in th internal/docker-push.
But error message is displayd  as belog:

```
Error interacting with this repository: gcr.io/my-gcr-project/wercker PUT https://gcr.io/v1/repositories/my-gcr-project/wercker/ returned 401
```

My wercker.yml is

```
steps:
  - internal/docker-push:
    username: _json_key
    password: $GCR_JSON_KEY_FILE
    registry: https://gcr.io
    repository: gcr.io/my-gcr-project/my-image-name
    tag: test
```

AND $GCR_JSON_KEY_FILE is Wercker Environment variables

It sets as follows :
(Values were masked.)

```
GCR_JSON_KEY_FILE: 

{
  "type": "",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 11):

After downloading the JSON key file from the Google Cloud Console, open it and delete the whitespaces. Leave it a single-line JSON. If you paste it as it is in the Wercker GUI, you'll have it polluted with '\n' and authentication with GCR will fail.

Comment: I don't know why your answer wasn't marked as correct. It definitely fixed it for me, I was having the same issue. Thank you!!

Comment: OSX / Linux users: `tr -d '\n' < path-to-key-file.json`

Answer (score 1):

Can you check that your YAML file is correctly formatted?

It looks like you're setting "internal/docker-push" to null, which is probably not what you want.

Try this:

```
steps:
  - internal/docker-push:
      username: _json_key
      password: $GCR_JSON_KEY_FILE
      registry: https://gcr.io
      repository: gcr.io/my-gcr-project/my-image-name
      tag: test
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you reach out to us on gcr-contact at google.com (only GCR folks can see this list) and provide slightly more information?  Just masking the `private_key` should be sufficient.

As a sanity check, does the `project_id` in your JSON key match `my-gcr-project`, which I believe (from your error) is `aagcp-1205`?